# uWebSockets.js The server drops the connection when sending the image

Tags: json, base64, ws

I want to send an image from js to the server on uWebSockets, here is my code

on the frontend

```
let photoBuffer = {}

async function uploadPhotos() {
    const files = elements.photoInput.files;

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        const fileName = file.name;
        photoBuffer[fileName] = await readFileAsBase64(file);

    }
}

function readFileAsBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result.split(',')[1]);
        reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e.target.error);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}


elements.chatSubmit.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {

    if (elements.chatMessage.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        await uploadPhotos();

        for (const name in photoBuffer) {
            ws.send(photoBuffer[name]);
        }

        console.log(photoBuffer)

        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            controller: 'chatController',
            action: 'submitChatMessage',
            data: {
                chatId: current.chatId,
                messageId: current.messageId,
                sender: store.userId,
                message: elements.chatMessage.value,
                adTitle: current.adTitle,
            },
        }));

        elements.chatMessage.value = '';
    }
});
```

on the backend

```
const app = require('uWebSockets.js').App({
    maxPayloadLength: 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
});
const config = require('./config/config');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const store = require('./store/store');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const controllers = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'controllers')).reduce((acc, file) => {
    const fileName = path.parse(file).name;
    acc[fileName] = require(`./controllers/${fileName}`);
    return acc;
}, {});

app.ws('/*', {
    open: async (socket, request) => {
        global.app = app;
        global.dir = __dirname;
    },
    message: async (socket, message, isBinary) => {
        if (isBinary){
            console.log(isBinary)
        }

        if (isBinary === false) {
            const {controller, action, data} = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(message).toString());
            console.log(controller)
            const control = controllers[controller];
            if (control && control[action]) {
                control[action](data, socket);
            }
        }

    },
    close: async (socket) => {
        if (socket.id !== undefined) {
            store.users[String(socket.id)] = {
                status: 'offline'
            }

            for (let id in store.users) {
                if (store.users[id].status === 'online') {
                    console.log(store.users[id]);
                    store.users[id].socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                        handler: 'statusHandler',
                        payload: {
                            id: socket.id,
                            status: 'offline'
                        }
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

(async () => {
    try {
        global.pool = await mysql.createPool(config.db);
        app.listen(config.main, () => {
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

I tried encoding both in base64 and in arraybuffer:

```
let photoBuffer

async function uploadPhotos() {
  let files = elements.photoInput.files;
  photoBuffer = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      let fileName = file.name;
      let arrayBuffer = await readFileAsArrayBuffer(file);
      photoBuffer[fileName] = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  }
}

function readFileAsArrayBuffer(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result)
        reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e.target.error)
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    })
}
```

I see in the console on the frontend that the image is there and converted to bytes, but as soon as I press send - the server crashes, and without any errors in the console
Maybe someone is familiar with this problem, I have spent more than two days but can not find a solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtChm.png)

Comment: Follow-up question: can you post the image via HTTP rather than use websockets?